# Should I use a local database or an XML file?

Tags: c#, .net, database

I should choose a persistent storage for my application and therefore I should decide whether to opt for a local database (in SQL Server Compact 3.5 Database) or an XML file. Basically, the application needs to update very frequently some of the data in a table: each row of this table consists of a GUID (as primary key), two `DateTime` columns, two `TimeSpan` columns, and four `double` columns.

This table might consist of thousands of rows, and some of these rows (about 10%) are updated very frequently, where each update consists of the following operations:

- retrieve the *current values* ​​related to a GUID;
- compare these values ​​with some data in order to obtain *new values*;
- overwrite the current values with the new values.

The rows that are updated (the above 10%) are not always the same, but they may change gradually during program execution.

If I store this table in an XML file, as soon as the application starts, the Data Access Layer loads the data from the XML file to a `Dictionary<Guid, ...>` in order to obtain better performance. Then when the application terminates, the XML file is overwritten with the data updated in the dictionary, because I believe that there is no way to update specific portions of an XML file. This is the approach I currently use.

1. What would be the advantages of using a local database instead of the XML file? I believe that if I use a local database, I could do without the `Dictionary<Guid, ...>`, then the Data Access Layer would be simpler.
2. What disadvantages could have the local database than the current "XML/Dictionary based" approach?

Comment: What happens if the user has your app open for a few hours and the  APP crashes before the XML is saved?

Comment: @Rippo: All updates would be lost. But if I make regular updates (overwriting) of the file, a smaller amount of updates would be lost.

Comment: Define "very frequently" - that's a fairly key bit of information...

Comment: @Murph: Roughly every 5 seconds.

Comment: Ok, in practical terms that's hardly very often at all... use a database.

Comment: @code4life: single user.

Comment: @enzom83, XML might not be a bad choice, especially if you map it to a domain POCO. Just as you would with a database, make sure to keep the data ACID by regularly persisting the data to file, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your application crashes, your XML file might not be saved. Or worse, it might be mangled. It is possible to mitigate this bug by wrapping your program in a `try`/`finally` and writing the XML in the `finally`, but this still opens you up to mangling the XML.

When you use a database, you guarantee that your transaction will be atomic - meaning a write will either fully complete or not happen at all. This is the primary benefit of using a database.

However, using the XML/Dictionary approach is still very fast due to the fact that it's all in-memory transactions. As long as you don't care about data integrity this is a very viable approach.

As far as a complicated data access layer, this can be an issue with either approach. Just keep this layer separate from your business logic and it shouldn't affect which you choose.

Comment: The other thing to add here is if this ever turns into a multiple user application then an in memory representation of the data is not going to cut the mustard.

Comment: definitely not going to "cut the mustard" ;)